# undefined plomb function in matlab

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing

let us consider following code

```
Fs = 1000;
f0 = 175;
f1 = 400;

t = 0:1/Fs:0.5;

wgn = randn(length(t),2)/2;
sigOrig = sin(2*pi*[f0;f1]*t)' + wgn;
```

from the following link

http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/plomb.html#buio4lp-13

i have applied this code

```
plomb(sigOrig,t)
```

but got following error

```
Undefined function 'plomb' for input arguments of type 'double'.
```

i have matlab 2014a, so what is  source of error?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you have MATLAB 2014a and not 2014b. `plomb` was introduced in R2014b, as you find out from [Signal Processing Toolbox 2014b Release Notes](http://ch.mathworks.com/help/signal/release-notes.html):

> Spectral estimation of signals with nonuniform sampling or missing data
>
> This release introduces a new spectral estimation function, `plomb`. The function can compute spectra of nonuniformly sampled signals or signals with missing samples by using the Lomb-Scargle algorithm. `plomb` also provides visualization functionality and support for multichannel data.

You'll either have to update to R2014b or create your own function.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...perhaps you do not have the toolbox in your Matlab 2014a... I use the 2014b and it works fine.

but you can still use functions written by trusted people:
You can try:
http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20004-lomb--lomb-scargle--periodogram
or alternatively
http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/993-lombscargle-m

Comment: i can't open neither link,could you please sent me code?